# Convert float to double

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point, double

I'm trying to convert `Single` to `Double` while maintaining the original value. I've found the following method:

```
Single f = 5.2F;
Double d1 = f; // 5.19999980926514
Double d2 = Double.Parse(f.ToString()); // 5.2 (correct)
```

Is this practice recommendable? I don't need an optimal method, but the intended value must be passed on to the double. Are there even consequences to storing a rounded value in a double?

Comment: Not all floating point numbers can be representing exactly, which is why 5.2 becomes 5.19999980926514.

Comment: From a binary standpoint, it is.  5.2 cannot be represented _exactly_ as a binary floating-point number, so it gives you the closest value it can.

Comment: I understand, but isn't a string conversion a bold move? Is it evitable?

Comment: What are you _doing_ with those numbers?  Yes, converting a single to a string and parsing to a double is probably not the best approach.

Comment: @DStanley - I'm not using them for operations, I'm storing them. The container objects do not natively support `System.Single` so I must convert them.

Comment: Are you sure that the `ToString()` does not do any rounding?

Comment: is the 5.2 hard-coded or the result of a calculation?  If the latter can you do the calculation with doubles to get greater precision?

Comment: @DStanley - Preferably hard-coded, but I may not assume either. Floating point logic is my absolute vice; what I really need to know is; how to convert `Single` to `Double` while maintaining representability in case the value was indeed hard-coded, as the values are serialized at some point. I think I understand that direct `Single` to `Double` conversion is not harmful, but this is an issue of presentation.

Comment: So how do you preferably want to display other long decimal places? If Pi were sent over for example? Perhaps just store a String.Format and fixed-point value perhaps? #.## so you would have 3.14 for Pi and 5.2...

Comment: @AustinFrench - The values aren't mine, I cannot justify _any_ additional adjustment beyond round-tripping to ensure successful deserialization.

Comment: Alright, then I'd stick with xanatos mention that they really are the same number just with different precision represented.

Answer (score 15):

You could use "decimal" instead of a string.

```
float f = 5.2F;
decimal dec = new decimal(f);//5.2
double d = (double)dec; //5.2
```

Answer (score 8):

The conversion is exact. All the `Single` values can be represented by a `Double` value, because they are "built" in the same way, just with more possible digits. What you see as *5.2F* is in truth `5.1999998092651368`. If you go http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html and insert *5.2* you'll see that it has an exponent of *2^2* (so *4*) and a mantissa of *1.2999999523162842*. Now, if you multiply the two numbers you'll get *5.1999998092651368*.

`Single` have a maximum precision of [7 digits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so .NET only shows 7 digits. With a little rounding *5.1999998092651368* is *5.2*

Comment: 5.1999998092651368 is itself a rounded value. It cannot be exactly represented as a binary fraction. The closest float to 5.2 is 5.19999980926513671875. The closest double to 5.2 is 5.20000000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125

Answer (score 0):

If you know that your numbers are multiples of e.g. 0.01, I would suggest that you convert to double, round to the nearest integer, and subtract that to get the fractional residue.  Multiply that by 100, round to the nearest integer, and then divide by 100.  Add that to the whole-number part to get the nearest `double` representation to the multiple of 0.01 which is nearest the original number.

Note that depending upon where the `float` values originally came from, such treatment may or may not improve accuracy.  The closest `float` value to 9000.02 is about 9000.019531, and the closest `float` value to 9000.021 is about 9000.021484f.  If the values were arrived at by converting 9000.020 and 9000.021 to `float`, the difference between them should be about 0.01.  If, however, they were arrived at by e.g. computing `9000f+0.019531f` and `9000f+0.021484f`, then the difference between them should be closer to 0.02.  Rounding to the nearest 0.01 before the subtract would improve accuracy in the former case and degrade it in the latter.